# Segmentation Fault occurs with arrays greater than 90 elements (Fortran-binding, cuBLAS)

Tags: arrays, cuda, fortran, intel-fortran, cublas

I'm writing a simple matrix vector multiplication program in Fortran. In this program I am making use of cuBLAS's Fortran Binding routines explained [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#appendix-b-cublas-fortran-bindings). The program works like a charm when my array contains less than 90 elements. I've read a few other posts suggesting to use `ulimit -s unlimited` or `-heap-array [size]`, but these didn't work in my case. Is there another method to solving this issue that I'm not aware of? I am compiling with ifort and gfortran, using nvcc to compile the cublas routines.

**ifort**

`$ifort -heap-arrays 1 -names uppercase -assume nounderscore -c -o cublasf.o main.f90
$nvcc -c -DCUBLAS_INTEL_FORTRAN -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/src -o fortran.o /usr/local/cuda/src/fortran.c
$ifort -heap-arrays 1 -o cublasf fortran.o cublasf.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcublas`

**gfortran**

`$gfortran -c -o cublasf.o main.f90
$nvcc -c -DCUBLAS_GFORTRAN -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/src -o fortran.o /usr/local/cuda/src/fortran.c
$gfortran -o cublasf cublasf.o fortran.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcublas`

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

### UPDATE

Here is the code that I am trying to run. I know it's not the prettiest code and there are some optimizations I can do, but it is only for testing at the moment. There are some elements commented out that are only used for testing purposes (no need to worry about those).

**main.f90**

```
program main

implicit none

INTEGER CUBLAS_INIT
INTEGER CUBLAS_ALLOC
INTEGER CUBLAS_FREE
INTEGER CUBLAS_SET_VECTOR
INTEGER CUBLAS_SET_MATRIX
INTEGER CUBLAS_GET_VECTOR
INTEGER CUBLAS_SGEMV
EXTERNAL CUBLAS_SGEMV
INTEGER CUBLAS_SHUTDOWN

integer :: countNumCuda, countNumCuda2,countNumFort,countNumFort2
integer :: clockRate = 4
integer*4, parameter :: N=80
real*4, dimension(N,N) :: mat
real*8 :: devPtr_mat, devPtr_vect, devPtr_outVect
real*4, dimension(N) :: vect,outVect,outVect2, anotherVect
integer :: i,j
integer :: size_of_real = 8
character :: trans = "N"
real*4 :: alpha = 1.0
real*4 :: beta = 0.0
integer :: cublas_status

! Initialize matrix and array 
do i = 1, N
  do j = 1, N
    mat(i,j) = i
  end do
  vect(i) = i
  outVect(i) = 0
  outVect2(i) = 0
end do

!call SYSTEM_CLOCK(countNumFort, clockRate)
!call MATRIXVECTORMULT(mat, vect, outVect, N)
!call SYSTEM_CLOCK(countNumFort2, clockRate)

!do i = 1, N
!  anotherVect(i) = outVect(i)
!enddo

call SYSTEM_CLOCK(countNumCuda, clockRate)
print*,"Entering GPU"
cublas_status = CUBLAS_INIT()
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "initialization error"
end if

cublas_status = CUBLAS_ALLOC(N*N,size_of_real, devPtr_mat)
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "Allocation error devMat"
end if

cublas_status = CUBLAS_ALLOC(N, size_of_real, devPtr_vect)
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "Allcoation error devVect"
end if

cublas_status = CUBLAS_ALLOC(N, size_of_real, devPtr_outVect)
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "Allocation error devPtrOut"
end if

cublas_status = CUBLAS_SET_VECTOR(N, size_of_real, vect, 1, devPtr_vect, 1)
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "Set vector error", cublas_status
end if

cublas_status = CUBLAS_SET_MATRIX(N,N,size_of_real, mat, N, devPtr_mat, N)
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "Set matrix error", cublas_status
end if

cublas_status = CUBLAS_SGEMV(trans,N,N,alpha, devPtr_mat, N, devPtr_vect,1,beta,devPtr_outVect,1)
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "SGEMV error", cublas_status
end if

cublas_status = CUBLAS_GET_VECTOR(N,size_of_real, devPtr_outVect, 1, outVect2, 1)
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "Get vector error", cublas_status
end if

cublas_status = CUBLAS_FREE(devPtr_mat)
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "free mat error", cublas_status
end if

cublas_status = CUBLAS_FREE(devPtr_vect)
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "free vect error", cublas_status
end if

cublas_status = CUBLAS_FREE(devPtr_outVect)
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "Free outVect error", cublas_status
end if

cublas_status = CUBLAS_SHUTDOWN()
if (cublas_status .NE. 0) then
  print *, "shutdown error", cublas_status
end if

call SYSTEM_CLOCK(countNumCuda2, clockRate)

!Results from CUDA
!do i = 1, N
! print *, anotherVect(i), outVect(i), outVect2(i)
!end do

do i = 1, N
  print*, outVect2(i)
enddo

!print *, countNumCuda2 - countNumCuda, "Cuda Rate"
!print *, countNumFort2 - countNumFort, "Fortran Rate"

end program main
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code by manually stepping through it using a debugger? Which line crashes? Can you post the code?

Comment: Do you mean less than or greater than 90 elements? The title says greater but in here you say less than.

Comment: The program crashes when greater than 90 elements. In the title it says it crashes with greater than 90 elements, but in the body I state  that it works like a charm with arrays containing less tan 90 elements. I'm working on posting my code,  I was away from my machine for a bit.

Comment: @LumpN I have added the code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A segmentation fault is arising out of host code or accessing variables that reside on the host.  When you ask for help on a seg fault here, it's good practice to identify the actual line of code or short section of code that is producing the seg fault.  It's a trivial matter to do this with a short code like this, simply by putting print statements liberally through the code and seeing which occur and which don't.

Your seg fault is due to the fact that you are allocating most of your host based storage as 4 byte reals:

```
real*4, dimension(N,N) :: mat
...
real*4, dimension(N) :: vect,outVect,outVect2, anotherVect
```

But when you attempt to copy them to the device, you are instructing cublas to assume each element is an 8-byte quantity:

```
integer :: size_of_real = 8
```

For me, the seg fault was occurring on this line of code:

```
cublas_status = CUBLAS_SET_MATRIX(N,N,size_of_real, mat, N, devPtr_mat, N)
```

This line is instructing `cublas` to copy the variable `mat` to the device.  But you are asking it to copy N*N*8 bytes, which is twice as big as your allocation.  As the copying routine goes beyond the end of your allocation for `mat`, a seg fault occurs (eventually).

Changing your declarations to indicate 8 bytes per real:

```
real*8, dimension(N,N) :: mat
...
real*8, dimension(N) :: vect,outVect,outVect2, anotherVect
```

eliminated the seg fault for me.